# Germanium Transistor

Tags: identification

I have a 3 lead AC125U Germanium Transistor with a little metal tab next to one of the outer leads, and a small red dot next to the opposite outer lead. I understand the middle lead to be the "base" lead. How do I identify the "collector" lead from the "emiter" lead.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The tab marks the emitter.

Photos from a transistor reference book are available on [DIY Guitar Pedals](http://www.diyguitarpedals.com.au/shop/datasheets/AC125_Datasheet.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

Transistor has already given you a datasheet reference +1, but in case that couldn't be found, another way is to set the transistor up as an amplifier and measure hFE (or just stick it into a DMM with an hFE function).

For most (not all) transistors, the forward gain will be much higher than the reverse gain (E and C swapped). If it's not much higher, it will usually be similar (symmetrical transistor) and it doesn't much matter which you use (it will also have  E-B reverse breakdown voltage similar to C-E).

Comment: A simpler and almost as good method is to measure the breakdown voltage BE and BC. Using a small current (~1ma) it is not likely to damage the transistor. BE reverse voltage will be few times less than BC reverse voltage.

Answer (score 2):

With silicium transistors, I can find out which one is the collector or the emitter by measuring the resistance between the base and the other 2 electrodes. The one with a lower resistance is the collector (sometimes this difference is very small, like less than 10 ohms out of about 600 ohms. Usually, the smaller the difference, the higher the gain of the transistor). Haven't had a chance to try a germanium transistor, but I suspect it would be the same.
And you already got the answer for this transistor: the emitter side is marked with a small tab.

Answer (score 0):

I quote: If your multimeter does have a "diode test" function that gives you the voltage drop across the forward-biased diode being tested, you can compare the voltage drop across the two diode candidates. The one with the higher voltage drop will correspond with the emitter of the transistor.

figuring out collector from emitter is a bit harder.   You can do it with two 9-volt batteries and a 3.3K resistor if you hook them all in series with a transistor, in one of the configurations the transistor's EB junction will zener at around 6 to 15 volts.    The collector junction is almost always not a zenerific one and will instead avalanche at 40 or more volts.

The collector and emitter can be identified knowing the fact that the doping for the B-E junction is always much higher than for the B-C junction, therefore, the forward voltage drop will be slightly higher. This will show up as a couple of millivolts difference on a digital multimeter's diode test scale or a slightly higher resistance on an analog VoltOhmMeter.